# How to find out a newly created Tag in SVN is Changed or Unchanged?

Tags: svn

For my product I have several components into it. But all the components don't change all the time. For a new release I create a tag from working trunk or branch (even though the component is changed or not) into SVN. And give the build on tags. Now I want to find out whether newly created tag has the code changes or not. Is there any SVN property or something useful available to easily find out that? Comparing the revision number of two tags is one solution but this is very difficult to find out which previous tag to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you components are subdirectories inside product dir and you tag always root of product you can diff two tags - new and previous

`svn diff OLD-TAG-URL NEW-TAG-URL` and *fact of any output* of diff will be sign of changes, diff content - actual aggregated changes

Comment: I also create branches from trunk and create tag from different branches. When a branch is new then I'll have only a single tag created from that branch. In this case how would I take the diff?

Comment: @geekEclipse - in **any** case I'll diff current (latest) tag with previous in timeline. Detection of previous isn't easiest game, but parsing output of `svn ls -v URL-OF-REPO/tags` will help (first column in list - revision, in which tag was crated)